# 10 kids have 100 balls in 10 different colors, each color has 10 balls. each ball can only be swapped once

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Suppose between $10$ kids we have $100$ balls in $10$ different colors, each color has $10$ balls.  Each kid has $10$ balls to start.

The only legal operation is letting two kids swap two balls between them. Each ball can only be swapped once. Prove that no matter what the initial config is, we can always make each kid have $10$ balls in $10$ different colors.

---

My thoughts: I started with $2$ by $2$, and that's trivial. But this seems to grow harder very quick when $n$ grows.

I wonder if we can map the configuration to a graph, and prove that there exists an Eulerian path of some sort?

Comment: I believe you can prove this by induction, but I don't have the time to do it properly. Let $f_i$ be the number of distinct color balls that kid $i$ has. We want $f_i=10 ~\forall i$. I think the following algorithm will work find $i$ and $k$ such that $f_i<10$ and $f_k<10$, swap their pair of balls that occur multiple times. This swap can only increase the values of $f_i$ and $f_k$, and never decrease them. So eventually all $f_i$ will become $10$.

Comment: Can you give the problem source, please? Just to ascertain that the contest deadline is in the past.

Comment: You might at least add the condition that each ball is swapped at most once to the problem statement.